# C++ Calling parent virtual function from pointer

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
void FAuCoreEditorModule::OnAssetEditorOpen(
    UObject* EditObject
  , IAssetEditorInstance* Toolkit)
{
    FName NAme = Toolkit->GetEditorName();
    if(Toolkit->GetEditorName() == "CurveTableEditor")
    {
        FAssetEditorToolkit* AET = static_cast<FAssetEditorToolkit*>(Toolkit);
        AET->FAssetEditorToolkit::RegisterTabSpawners(AET->GetTabManager().ToSharedRef());
    }
}
```

The `Toolkit` is of type `ICurveTableEditor`.

```
RegisterTabSpawners
```

Is virtual function in `FAssetEditorToolkit`.
CurveTableEditor implements it, but never call to parent. I wanted to call parent implementation, without modyfing original source code. Came up with this:

```
FAssetEditorToolkit* AET = static_cast<FAssetEditorToolkit*>(Toolkit);
AET->FAssetEditorToolkit::RegisterTabSpawners(AET->GetTabManager().ToSharedRef());
```

It this legal ? Or it just work by accident ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It this legal ?

Potentially yes. Not necessarily.

Static downcasting is allowed if `IAssetEditorInstance` is a non-virtual unambiguous base of `FAssetEditorToolkit` and if the pointer is truly to an object of such type (or a type with such non-virtual base).

If some of those restrictions are not satisfied, you can use `dynamic_cast` instead (as long as the base is polymorphic). Make sure to check whether it returns null or not.